# Chrome extension popup page link doesn't work

Tags: popup, google-chrome-extension

I was creating a Chrome extension for fun, but i got a problem with my popup page. I used jQuery load() function to load a part of existed page, let's say: http://aaa.com:

```
<div id="aaa-news">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#ox-news").load("http://aaa/News/ .news_list");
});
</div>
```

Since the part of page i tried to load into popup.html contains some links, but seems href attributes of these links have been modified by Chrome whenever they are loaded in popup.html.So even if i used chrome.tabs.create.* API to open a new tab, it always showed me

No webpage was found for the web address:
**Chrome extension://phigdpgmolbpdcihdohfpbafibncbkhl/News/1** 
Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.

Anyone has idea? Appreciated for your help!

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to load contents of an external (not contained with the extension) page in to your popup and that the relative links loaded within are not opening correctly? If so, the only clean fix I can think of is to change the source of the links to be absolute (e.g. `<a href="http://aaa/News/1">` instead of `<a href="News/1">`.

If you are unable to change the source (i.e. it doesn't belong to you) then you may have to be clever and make the links absolute if they are relative.

Comment: @Alasdair: exactly pointed! First,i am unable to change the source, so i am thinking maybe i can change the relative links to absolute ones, but that has lot of hard coding, how can i change them dynamically? What if they update the site, add one more news?

Comment: Unfortunately this is no easy task and I can only suggest you keep an eye on your source for changes to its links. If they are simple relative links (e.g. `News/1`) then you can simply prepend the source page URL to that in order for it to work. However, this could get complicated if they have links that are more complex (`../News/1`, `/News/1` etc). I just stumbled across [this script](http://www.phpied.com/relative-to-absolute-links-with-javascript/) which might help but I don't have time to test it right now. Good luck!

Comment: If you had access to the source page's DOM maybe `url = location.resolveURL(url);` could work. However, this will probably just create a link relative to your extensions path if used :(

Answer (score 7):

To fix relative links you can use `<base>` tag. It is also useful to make all links inside popup to open in a tab by setting `target="_blank"` (otherwise links become non-clickable):

```
<base href="http://aaa/" />
<base target="_blank" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, but my problem is the link address of href attribute will be modified when i extracted from other site and embeded in popup.html page, normally it should: "http://aaa/bbb/c", but now it became "chrome://phigdpgmolbpdcihdohfpbafibncbkhl/bbb/c", i tried what you said, but seems not working. i replace <a> tag with <base> tag, add target="_blank" attribute in the <base> tag, but it didn't work...

Comment: @Jianinz You don't need to replace `<a>` tags with `<base>`, you need to add `<base>` inside `<head>`. Are you 100% sure Chrome replaces the links? It shouldn't. Have you inspected popup source to see what's inside html?

Comment: Yes, i am sure the link has been replaced, probably due to relative links in the source code of external page. I am thinking that even if i add the '<base>' inside '<head>', but i am unable to modified all relative links, that's too much work...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it by using the following chrome extension :

New Tab Redirect! 2.0

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna

Click the original chrome pages "New Tab" button on the tab that appears the after installation of this extension.