# Chrome Extension unable to open link

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, button, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that includes a few buttons that take the user to some websites through URLs retrieved from a JSON file. The issue is that chrome is adding chrome-extension://(my chrome extension domain) to the start of the href URL of every single button. For example, the URL will be chrome-extension://(my chrome extension domain)/www.google.com/ instead of [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) as the href. Due to this, I am getting a (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found error once the page opens with that URL in a new tab. I am setting the href to the correct URL and I am using target = '_blank'. Why does chrome keep doing that? My other chrome extensions seem to be working fine, and I have used the same method throughout. Is this a bug?

There was no real answer here: [Chrome extension popup page link doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851606/chrome-extension-popup-page-link-doesnt-work?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: You're setting `href` to a relative URL. The solution is to use a full URL with `https://` scheme.

Comment: @wOxxOm but then some URLs will not work because some use HTTP. The JSON has thousands of objects with URL's and they all start with www. How would I able to know whether the website is using HTTP or HTTPS. And is there any documentation of this problem that occurs when building chrome extensions?

Comment: Then you can use `http://` and the site will automatically redirect to `https`. Thing is, chrome extension pages have `chrome-extension://` protocol so you have to specify protocol for your links.